# Issues with CSS property 'float'

Tags: html, css, css-float

I'm trying to responsively position four `div` elements. My approach is to use the CSS `float:left` statement ([jsFiddle code example](http://jsfiddle.net/t969q/4/)).

CSS

```
.smart-box {
    width: 28%;
    min-width: 330px;
    margin-right: 4%;
    vertical-align: top;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="smart-box">
    <h3>Category 1</h3>
    <ul>    
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="smart-box">
    <h3>Category 2</h3>
    <ul>    
        <li>...</li>
    </ul>
</div>

...
```

This is an example with desired behaviour of those boxes.

[image: Screenshot #1]

---

### Problem

But when the window is (horizontally) too small, the boxes behave in an unwanted way (see screenshot).

[image: Screenshot #2]

What do I have to modify to either place `#4` under `#1` or in the order drafted below?

```
+-----+    +-----+
|  1  |    |  3  |
+-----+    +-----+

+-----+    +-----+
|  2  |    |  4  |
+-----+    +-----+
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce the issue in either ie11 or chrome.

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to get the result you showed in your first image is to remove `float: left` and instead use `inline-block`:

```
.smart-box {
    display: inline-block; 
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

Comment: Indeed. We're floating way too often! And with IE7 having left the building, browser support for `inline-block` is nothing to be worried about anymore. +1.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to use media queries to add new styles when a screen width gets below a certain size.

```
@media screen and (max-width:820px) {
    .smart-box3{
        clear:both;
    }
}
}
```

(I had to give the third box a class of smart-box3)

See: http://jsfiddle.net/LP9bz/

NB It is wrapping like that because the first box is taller than the second.  You could also use javascript to set the height of all the boxes to match the tallest one.

Comment: This is a pretty good solution, except I should note that this is a good place to use :nth-of-type or :nth-child instead of adding an extra class to clear it. Digg's new front page is a good example of that kind of technique.

Comment: Yeah, you are right.  That would keep the code tidier.